# Add Videoview programmatically

Tags: firebase, video-streaming

Iam trying to add a videoview with content from firebase but it's not working.
Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code ? The app iss crashing with this error log :

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference

Here's the code

```
       if(dataSnapshot.child("video1").exists()){
                LinearLayout 
linearLayout=findViewById(R.id.linearlayoutmore);

                String 
video=dataSnapshot.child("video1").getValue().toString();

                VideoView vid= new VideoView(entProfileFull.this);
                vid.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(String.valueOf(video)));
                linearLayout.addView(vid);
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams=vid.getLayoutParams();
                vid.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                MediaController mediaController = new 
MediaController(getApplicationContext());
                vid.setMediaController(mediaController);
                vid.requestFocus();
                vid.seekTo(100);
```

Comment: `linearLayout` is null.  It doesn't exist in your view hierarchy.

Comment: But I do have a linear layout with that id. I checked and double-checked. It's there

Comment: I dunno, Android seems to think differently.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)